# Python Internet Explorer driver using its own proxy instead of the proxy I have set

Tags: python, selenium-iedriver, browsermob-proxy, iedriverserver

The browser traverses all the webpages correctly but is listening on a different port in spite of specifying the port in the below code. I am trying to initiate the internet explorer driver using selenium and browsermob-proxy with the following code:

```
    #Set up the BroserMob-Proxy Client and Server
    proxy = ProxyManager()
    server = proxy.start_server()
    client = proxy.start_client()
    
    #Set up the Internet Explorer driver and open the link creating an HAR file on the proxy server
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()
    capabilities['ensureCleanSession'] = True        
    capabilities["proxy"] = { "proxyType": "manual", "httpProxy": client.proxy }
    capabilities['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
    capabilities['IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings'] = True
    capabilities['nativeEvents'] = True
    capabilities['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
    capabilities['requireWindowFocus'] = True
    capabilities['INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'] = True
    
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Ie(IEdriver, capabilities=capabilities)
    except:
        print("Error setting up IE driver. Please verify that path supplied to the internet explorer driver is correct.")
        sys.exit()
```